# Android parse String into StringDef

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have declared a `@StringDef` in my code :

```
@StringDef({NotificationAction.DISPLAYED, NotificationAction.CONTENT_CLICKED,
    NotificationAction.ACTION_CLICKED, NotificationAction.DISMISSED})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface NotificationAction {
    String DISPLAYED = "Displayed";
    String CONTENT_CLICKED = "ContentClicked";
    String ACTION_CLICKED = "ActionClicked";
    String DISMISSED = "Dismissed";
}
```

How do I parse a new string into a NotificationAction without individually comparing it with each of them?

In enum, I can directly use `valueOf` function. I couldn't find anything similar here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cannot really do anything else but implementing it. What I did is the following.

```
public class Job {

    @IntDef(value = {
            Status.STOPPED,
            Status.STARTED,
            Status.NEW
    })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @interface JobStatus {
    }

    public static class Status {
        public static final int STOPPED = 0;
        public static final int STARTED = 1;
        public static final int NEW = 2;

        @JobStatus
        static int getStatus(int status) {
            return status;
        }

        @JobStatus
        static int fromName(String name) {
            switch (name) {
                case "STOPPED":
                    return STOPPED;
                case "STARTED":
                    return STARTED;
                case "NEW":
                    return NEW;
                default:
                    return NEW;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it can help you.